# Filtering a MS Access form between dates and a third field

Tags: vba

I am trying to filter a form between two dates and not equal to a third criteria. All three criteria's are in form fields. Note that this is not a "or" statement but rather all three criteria's must be met to return a record. Below is the statement that I have set on click for a form button.

```
 Me.Filter = "[dt] BETWEEN #" & Me.StartDate & "# AND #" & Me.EndDate & "#"
 Me.FilterOn = True
```

I need to add the third criteria from a form field in the same form as "List54" which has a control source of [Status]. The valid status for returning a record would be not equal to "Closed". Note that "Open" or null field would be alternatively acceptable to return a record.

Comment: I apologize but I actually need to have the VBA filter for >= Me.StartDate and <=Me.EndDate and also the third value within the control ([Status])

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Me.Filter = "[dt] BETWEEN #" & Me.StartDate & "# AND #" & Me.EndDate & "# AND NZ(Me.Control,""Open"") = 'Open'"
```

Replace `Me.Control` with the actual control reference.

Comment: It will not include null fields but I can set the field to default to "Open" upon adding a new record which should be done anyway. I am still testing the rest.

Comment: If it'll never be null then you can do away with the `NZ` bit and just check if it's Open - my answer, or not Closed - @Kostas answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set the rule to the recordset directly.

```
With Me
    .Filter = "[dt] BETWEEN #" & Me.StartDate & "# AND #" & Me.EndDate & "# AND Nz([Status],'Open')<>'Closed'"
    .FilterOn = True
End With
```

Comment: Would that still work if `Status` was Null?  I'd have thought you'd get some kind of invalid use of null error?

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook Not as far as I know.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook As a matter of fact, NULL does not throw an error but it doesn't return as well.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion but the code below works, howerver then I realized that I wanted

(>= Me.StartDate and <= Me.EndDate) and [Status] = Open. 

Me.Filter = "[dt] BETWEEN #" & Me.StartDate & "# AND #" & Me.EndDate & "# AND NZ([Status],""Open"") = 'Open'"
Me.FilterOn = True

Can someone help with that?